# How would I outline a UILabel in black?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uilabel

I have some white text but I want to outline in black (in my iPhone application). In my custom UILabel's drawRect method, how would I outline all the letters in black?

Can someone show code that would do this? Thanks!